# Import jquery with ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Since ember-cli 0.0.34 jquery is removed from the .jshint file as predefined.
So jquery needs to be imported, but I get the following error when doing it:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

The error I get is:

```
ENOENT, no such file or directory 'S:\...\tmp\tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-Nb27WzDk.tmp\jquery.js'
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'S:\...\tmp\tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-Nb27WzDk.tmp\jquery.js'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:684:18)
    at addModule (S:\...\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-es6-concatenator\index.js:81:46)
    .....
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I solved the problem by not importing jquery at all. jQuery is available via Ember.$ ([link](http://emberjs.com/api/#method__))

So I changed my code to use `Ember.$(...)` instead of `$(...)`

Comment: When I try to do this I get an error saying Ember.$(...) not defined :( any ideas?

Comment: @thecodethinker: make sure you have included `import Ember from 'ember';`  at the top of your file and use a recent ember-cli version.

Comment: To avoid changing every instance of `$` in a file you can just throw `var $ = Em.$;` below `import Em from 'ember';`

Comment: I went with @DuncanWalker but: `var $ = Ember.$;` under the 'import Em from 'ember';' Yay.

Comment: how to import jqueryui that is included in the brocfile?

Answer (score 5):

I've ran into the same problem after I updated `ember-cli` to 0.0.34.  Although I was still able to use `$` (jQuery) in my code, JSHint kept throwing the error:

`project/views/blah.js: line 6, col 9, '$' is not defined.`

You can edit your `.jshintrc` and add `$` back to `predef`.

```
{
  "predef": {
    // ...
    "$": true,
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

---

Would definitely prefer a method using `import` too.

Not sure if this will be of any help, but I was able to locate the file during build by using the line below, but it caused some issues in the browser:

`import $ from 'vendor/jquery/dist/jquery';`

Comment: Yes, this does work. But then jquery will be transmitted twice: Once in your cendor.js and once packed into your application-name-compiled-file.js.

Answer (score 2):

**$** becomes available after rendering / instantiation, as per usual use of jQuery.

If jQuery is desired to be used otherwise is requires the **Ember** prefix.

Handlebars is likewise available as Ember.Handlebars, albeit the Ember extended version.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was true at one time, but it is not true as of Ember 1.12.

Comment: Ha! Yeah. Considering the age of this post, this was for 0.7 or 0.8.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this code to my JS file

import jQuery from 'ember';

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Ember/Ember-CLI allow for destructuring, making importing libraries much easier.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { $, get, set } = Ember;
```

Would bring in jquery, getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've listed `@ember/jquery` in your `dependencies` within `package.json` of the consumed app/addon.  It might look something like this:

```
"@ember/jquery": "^1.1.0"
```

Then you can continue to use [jquery in the recommended way](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0176-javascript-module-api.md#jquery):

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
```